# Как парсить AliExpress?

Tags: java

какие есть инструменты для парсинга AliExpress используя java? пробовал разными способами, но данные не приходили после парсинга.

Comment: Привет, готовых инструментов нет. И лучше конкретизируй вопрос, что именно надо парсить.

Comment: Наверное вам эмуляция браузера нужна. Посмотрите на `Silenium`

Comment: Мне нужно парсить информацию о товарах, т.е. цену, название и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так используйте официальное API: https://portals.aliexpress.com/help.htm?page=help_center_api&

Я лично его не тестил, но судя по документации там есть всё что вам нужно.

Comment: Я пробовал, там надо доказать что ты продавец или супер-блоггер с подписчиками. А иначе не дадут ключа.